# Risk if comment out existing code that doesn't compile in current version?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

We're running Access 2016 in our office, and I have a database with macros, reports that fail to compile. Various compilation errors take place, e.g:

```
Application.Volatile --> Method or data member not found
If Me.Filter = "" Then --> Invalid use of Me keyword
Me.PageBreak1.Visible --> Method or data member not found 
etc.
```

Will this code ever run (now/in 2016) if it won't compile? I.e. are there old compiled binaries somewhere that still work? If I comment out code that triggers these compilation errors am I risking breaking something that does still work? ... Or is it safe to comment unable to compile code because it *cannot* work?

Answer (score 1):

Forms, objects, and the database itself can contain compiled code that honestly is more likely to make your application crash than work properly if the uncompiled variant hits compile errors. Also, Access might compile parts of the application, while not hitting compile errors that occur in other parts. But the compile errors are there for a reason.

While the code can possibly work fine with `Option Explicit` removed to make it compile, it's likely not doing what the author intended it to do.

Honestly, understanding the code is the only way to know if the code might be influenced when commenting something out. For example, if you comment out `If Me.Filter = "" Then`, then you will need to check for `Else` and `ElseIf` statements, and comment out the corresponding `End If`, or you will run into another compile error.

However, commenting out `Application.Volatile` is likely to do nothing at all, since this likely is a remainder of code being copied from Excel, and Access always recalculates.

So, good luck reading and comprehending all that legacy code (or employing trial and error).

Answer (score 1):

```
If Me.Filter = "" Then --> Invalid use of Me keyword
```

This can't fail if the code belongs to a form or report.

So, go to menu *Tools, References*, and check for any reference marked MISSING.

If found, correct this.

It is always safe to comment out code that won't run.

Eric is right; the Volatile method looks like a left-over from Excel, so you may face a larger clean-up project before the code will compile.